# Delphi generic class usage compilation error

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe

I'm writing some utility code for an old Delphi XE codebase; in order to keep things simpler and safer I've created a method meant to wrap a type-specific `TProc<TReq>` (where `TReq` is a generic class type) passed via parameters in a more broad `TProc<TObject>` that should be fed to a third-party component later on, along with `TClass(TReq)` and an additional string argument:

```
type
  TREvoHostConnectionOptions = record
    // [...]
    procedure OnPush<TReq:class>(const pushMethod: string; const action: TProc<TReq>);
  end;

// [...]

procedure TREvoHostConnectionOptions.OnPush<TReq>(const pushMethod: string; const action: TProc<TReq>);
    var
      rec: TRPushHandler;
    begin
      rec.PushMethod := pushMethod;
      rec.PushModel := TClass(TReq);
      rec.Handler :=
        procedure(reqRawModel: TObject)
          var
            reqModel: TReq;
          begin
            // Conversione modello richiesta
            reqModel := reqRawModel as TReq;
            if Assigned(reqRawModel) and not Assigned(reqModel) then
              raise EEvoHostException.Create(Format('Impossibile convertire il modello di tipo %s in %s.', [reqRawModel.ClassName, TClass(TReq).ClassName]));
            // Azione
            if Assigned(action) then
              action(reqModel);
          end;
      PushHandlers.Add(rec);
    end;
```

The previous method compiles successfully and if invoked like this, works as intended (although, having `TObject` as the generic type defeats the purpose of the method):

```
opts.OnPush<TObject>('Test', procedure (reqModel: TObject) begin (* ... *) end);
```

However, if in the testing form unit I invoke it with a specifically crafted model class:

```
  type
    TTestModel = class(TObject)
      strict private
        _a, _b: string;
      public
        property A: string read _a write _a;
        property B: string read _b write _b;
    end;
```

I get the following compiler error in a completely irrelevant line (and completely different and totally unrelated method) in the calling unit:

> **[DCC Error] WndMain.pas(96): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TTestModel' and 'TObject'**

* The displacement only occurs with this specific error, if I introduce an artificial syntax error anywhere else in the same file it gets reported at the correct line.

---

Any thoughts? Is this a compiler bug, and if so is there any way to get around it? Unfortunately I can't remove the `:class` constraint on the method because otherwise the `TClass(TReq)` conversion that happens inside the method raises (logically) another compilation error about `TReq` not being a constrained class or interface type.

Comment: Off-topic hint: Instead of `Exception.Create(Format('Error %d', [123]))`, try `Exception.CreateFmt('Error %d', [123])`.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget about CreateFmt. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, the problem seems to be caused by the `as` conversion in the method, even though it was reported in the wrong file.

Changing the method like this seems to have solved it:

```
procedure TREvoHostConnectionOptions.OnPush<TReq>(const pushMethod: string; const action: TProc<TReq>);
    var
      rec: TRPushHandler;
    begin
      rec.PushMethod := pushMethod;
      rec.PushModel := TClass(TReq);
      rec.Handler :=
        procedure(reqRawModel: TObject)
          var
            reqModel: TReq;
          begin
            // Conversione modello richiesta
            if Assigned(reqRawModel) and not reqRawModel.ClassType.InheritsFrom(rec.PushModel) then
              raise EEvoHostException.CreateFmt('Impossibile convertire il modello di tipo %s in %s.', [reqRawModel.ClassName, rec.PushModel.ClassName]);
            // Azione
            if Assigned(action) then
              action(TReq(reqModel));
          end;
      PushHandlers.Add(rec);
    end;
```